# Merge elements in JSON within Mule 4

Tags: json, mule, dataweave, mulesoft

I have the following SQL Server select query:

```
SELECT s.RefId
          ,s.LocalId
          ,s.StateProvinceId
          ,s.SchoolName
          ,e.Email
          ,e.EmailType
      FROM SchoolInfo s
      LEFT OUTER JOIN SchoolEmail e
      ON    e.SchoolRefId = s.RefId
      WHERE s.RefId = :ref_id
```

Converted to JSON in DataWeave:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "StateProvinceId": "SA",
    "RefId": "7FDF722B-6BBA-4BF0-8205-A5380B269EF1",
    "EmailType": "prm",
    "LocalId": "1",
    "SchoolName": "Steve's School",
    "Email": "steven@email.com"
  },
  {
    "StateProvinceId": "SA",
    "RefId": "7FDF722B-6BBA-4BF0-8205-A5380B269EF1",
    "EmailType": "sec",
    "LocalId": "1",
    "SchoolName": "Steve's School",
    "Email": "test@gmail.com"
  }
]
```

But I wish to have it merged by the common elements to generate the desired output of:

```
{
  "RefId": "7FDF722B-6BBA-4BF0-8205-A5380B269EF1",
  "LocalId": "1",
  "StateProvinceId": "SA",
  "SchoolName": "Steve's School",
  "Emails": [
    {
      "Email": "steven@email.com",
      "EmailType": "prm"
    },
    {
      "Email": "test@gmail.com",
      "EmailType": "sec"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I do that in Mule 4?

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or even this

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var Emails =  
    "Emails": payload map {
      Email: $.Email,
      EmailType: $.EmailType
}

---
payload distinctBy($.StateProvinceId) map {
  StateProvinceId: $.StateProvinceId,
  RefId: $.RefId,
  Emails:  Emails.Emails
}
```

Comment: Thanks Salim! I was trying to do everything after the ---, I didnt even think of extracting the Emails like this!

Questions: Why did you do the distinctBy StateProvinceID?

This looks like it generates an array:
[
  {
    "RefId": "7FDF722B-6BBA-4BF0-8205-A5380B269EF1",
    "LocalId": "1",
    "SchoolName": "Steve's School",
    "StateProvinceId": "SA",
    "Emails": [
      {
        "Email": "steven@gmail.com",
        "EmailType": "prm"
      },
      {
        "Email": "test@gmail.com",
        "EmailType": "sec"
      }
    ]
  }
]
How can we remove the top array?

Comment: distinctBy so that you don't repeat the keys that you need only once in the input. As well you could do something like this to get the output

Comment: Do you happen to have some other inputs (different stateProvinceId)  that would help make it a generic solution.

Comment: RefId is the unique key, so I think  distinctBy on that element should be fine. "As well you could do something like this to get the output " - did you finish your message?

Comment: yup .. posted below by accessing the [0]the element of the final array

Comment: Your example was added in a different section of the page. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

@Salim Khan answer is perfectly right. Just adding up `reduce` to convert array to object as a last bit to match exactly with your response format

```
%dw 2.0
var email =   payload map (item,index) -> { 
"Email":item.Email,
"EmailType":item.EmailType }

output application/json
---
 payload distinctBy($.StateProvinceId) map  {
"StateProvinceId": $.StateProvinceId,
"RefId": $.RefId,
 "LocalId":  $.LocalId,
"SchoolName": $.SchoolName,
"Emails":email } reduce $
```

Comment: Is the reduce $ better than the [0] array?